# How do I Create a Loop That Will Return The Days on the Month for my Code?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int[] daysInMonth = new int[31];
       for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
           System.out.println("Day of the month: " + daysInMonth[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

I recognize that I could hard code the values for each day of the month. I could do: daysInMonth[0] = 1; for all of the values in the month, but would like to use a loop to do this instead for the sake of efficiency. How would I create a loop that would output "Days of the month: 1, Day of the Month: 2, etc?"

Comment: So you just want to output the values `1` to `31`?  Sounds like you can just output the value of `i + 1` then, the `daysInMonth` array adds no value.

Comment: Why use an array if you can just print `i+1`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need an array, just write `i` in output and change loop parameters like that

```
for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
    System.out.println("Day of the month: " + i);
}
```

Comment: This ended up working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array length in iterating through the loop, since months have different lengths, and print i instead of an index [i] of your array.

```
 int[] daysInMonth = new int[31];
   for (int i = 0; i <= daysInMonth.length-1; i++) {
       System.out.println("Day of the month: " + (i+1));
   }
```